# Football team entity relationship diagram

Tags: mysql, erd, lucidchart

[image: My entity relationship diagram for a football team]

My teacher tested this structure by testing it within access and creating a form which queried the database. It came back as erroneous, i don't mind if it can't be fixed but i need to know what it wrong with it. 
Thanks

Comment: why don't you ask your teacher?

Comment: He didn't know ffs *laughing emoji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test it but I think you should be able to create a database from your model.

However, there are some logical errors I detected:

- the cardinality between team and position seems wrong as you modeled it a team only has one position and a position can belong to several teams
- also, your tables `position` and `manager` contain no information in your current model and are therefore unnecessary

Heres how I would probably model it set the attributes and cardinalities according to your requirements:

[image: model]

Comment: Thanks that really helpful!

Comment: @ProgrammingNinja glad it helped